# Large FedAuth Cookie (FedAuth4) with only 7 claims

Tags: federated-identity, wif

I'm struggling to figure out why a `ClaimsPrincipal` with only 7 claims is producing 5 `FedAuth` Cookies (FedAuth1, FedAuth2, FedAuth3, FedAuth4) from the FAM.

This is causing problems as Safari is truncating my cookies and my mac users are unable to login.

Any ideas why I might be experiencing this or where I can look to figure it out?

**UPDATE**: As pointed out by Eugenio setting SaveBootstrapTokens=false shrunk the cookies from 5 back to 2 and now safari users can log in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do these claims contain? The number of claims will affect the size of the token, but so will the information they have. The FedAuthx cookies are essentially the entire token (more specifically a ***SessionToken***), encrypted and chunked.

As an alternative you can consider using WIF "session mode" which will store the token on the server side. The tradeoff is having to manage the server side state and its consequences (e.g. state across web farms, etc)

**Update:**
You can control the size of each cookie with additional config. The minimum size is 1000 though and you can't control the total amount of cookies.

```
<cookieHandler requireSsl="false" mode="Chunked">
  <chunkedCookieHandler chunkSize="1000"/>
</cookieHandler>
```

The workaround mentioned in the article seems similar to what WIF does out of the box with "session mode" explained above. I'd suggest using this approach instead of a custom one. Vittorio's article explains it very well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2010/05/26/your-fedauth-cookies-on-a-diet-issessionmode-true.aspx

Comment: In my opinion the claims are small - I think something is wrong here is my full set of claims on the Identity in my RP:

Comment: I am running my own STS based on ThinkTechture.IdentityServer at https://accounts.climbfind.com/ - my RP is http://cf4.climbfind.com/

Comment: IS there a way for me to hook into wif and set the nameidentifier claim to my user Id, that way I could drop my custom userid claim (bringing it down to 6 claims)

Comment: Btw Eugenio, thanks for always being awesome on WIF related posts!!

Comment: Thanks, I've come across these articles / links before & if that is the only way to deal with it, I will go that route. I'm just wondering though, does the claim set in the comment above seem like something that would expand into 5 default chunkSize cookies? I feel like there has to be something wrong? Otherwise I'm just surprised that WIF is that bloated - the cookie seems far far bigger than the original claims...

Comment: Are you saving the bootstraptpoken by any chance? I wrote a simple test case with exactly your claimset and I only see 2 FedAuth cookies. If I set "savebootstraptoken=true", then it jumps to 4; which makes sense because you are essentially roughly doubling the information.

Answer (score 2):

The cookie limitation is a known issue with WIF and Safari.  Take a look here at the official bug report and work-around, which helps to limit the size of the token:

http://connect.microsoft.com/site642/feedback/details/573602/w-i-f-session-cookies-are-truncated-when-combined-size-4000-bytes-in-safari-and-opera